# How to get the value of <select> inside <td> only if <select> tag presents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page with its associated js file. the purpose is to convert data inserted into the table into a JSON file. User can edit table cells, and click the button so Javascript file parses the data and send it as an Ajax request to a PHP file on the server. The PHP file then stores the data as a file on the server and sends the link back.
For the  tags, I need to use val() instead of text() to get the selected value. However, val() returns an empty string. How to make it return value correctly?

```js
var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
var $EXPORT = $('#export');

$('.table-add').click(function () {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});

$('.table-remove').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});

$('.table-up').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return; // Don't go above the header
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});

$('.table-down').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});

// A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

$BTN.click(function () {
 //alert("ok");
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];
  
  // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
  
  // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
  $rows.each(function () {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};
    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach(function (header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).val();  
  alert($td.eq(i).val());
    });
    
    data.push(h);
  });
  
  // Output the result
  normaldata = JSON.stringify(data);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "filemaker.php",
      data:  {"data":normaldata},
      success: function(output) {

         
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = 'data.gmp'
  a.download = "data.gmp";
  a.click();
  //alert("reached here");
    }
});

  
});
```

```css
.table-editable {
  position: relative;
}
.table-editable .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.table-remove {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-remove:hover {
  color: #f00;
}

.table-up, .table-down {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-up:hover, .table-down:hover {
  color: #00f;
}

.table-add {
  color: #070;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
}
.table-add:hover {
  color: #0b0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML5 Editable Table</title>
  
  
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
<a href='text.html' >aa</a>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>HTML5 Editable Table</h1>
  <p>Through the powers of <strong>contenteditable</strong> and some simple jQuery you can easily create a custom editable table. No need for a robust JavaScript library anymore these days.</p>
  
  <ul>
    <li>An editable table that exports a hash array. Dynamically compiles rows from headers</li> 
    <li>Simple / powerful features such as add row, remove row, move row up/down.</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Doctor</th>
        <th>Specialization</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Area</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true"> 
  <select> 
   <option value='pharmacist'>Pharmacist</option>
   <option value='doctor'>Doctor</option>
  </select>
   </td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
         <td contenteditable="true"> 
  <select> 
   <option value='A+'>A+</option>
   <option value='A'>A</option>
   <option value='B'>B</option>
   <option value='C'>C</option>
  </select>
   </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
    
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
    <td contenteditable="true"> 
  <select> 
   <option value='pharmacist'>Pharmacist</option>
   <option value='doctor'>Doctor</option>
  </select>
   </td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> 
  <select> 
   <option value='A+'>A+</option>
   <option value='A'>A</option>
   <option value='B'>B</option>
   <option value='C'>C</option>
  </select>
   </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
 
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data</button>
  <p id="export"></p>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.text()` and `.val()` return completely different pieces of data. The first gives you the text content *inside the tag*, the other *the `value` attribute*.

Comment: @vlaz I know, but that is the question, why am i not getting the value?

Comment: The `<td>` elements don't have values. "The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`." -- [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: @showdev Thank you. Is there any workaround to get the values from the <select> tags inside the <td>

Comment: You can...select the `select` tag.

Comment: You want to get the `val()` of a `<select>` inside the `<td>` when one exists and the `text()` of the `<td>` otherwise?

Comment: @vlaz this works, but then the values of the other columns which don't contain <select> won't be returned.

Comment: @showdev exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following jQuery methods:

> The [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.
>
> The result of the [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.

For each table cell, it seems that you want to return the `val()` of the child `<select>`, if one exists, and the `text()` of the `<td>` otherwise.

Using JavaScript's [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), we can choose `text()` or `val()` depending on which one exists:

> Logical OR (||)
> expr1 || expr2
> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2.

Like this:

```
$select.val() || $td.text()
```

Here's an example:

```js
var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
var $EXPORT = $('#export');

$('.table-add').click(function() {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});

$('.table-remove').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});

$('.table-up').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return; // Don't go above the header
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});

$('.table-down').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});

// A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

$BTN.click(function() {
  //alert("ok");
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];

  // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function() {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });

  // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
  $rows.each(function() {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};
    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
      var $td = $tds.eq(i);
      var $select = $td.find('select');
      h[header] = $select.val() || $td.text();
      console.log(h[header]);
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.table-editable {
  position: relative;
}

.table-editable .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.table-remove {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-remove:hover {
  color: #f00;
}

.table-up,
.table-down {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-up:hover,
.table-down:hover {
  color: #00f;
}

.table-add {
  color: #070;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
}

.table-add:hover {
  color: #0b0;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div id="table" class="table-editable">
  <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Doctor</th>
      <th>Specialization</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <select>
          <option value='pharmacist'>Pharmacist</option>
          <option value='doctor'>Doctor</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <select>
          <option value='A+'>A+</option>
          <option value='A'>A</option>
          <option value='B'>B</option>
          <option value='C'>C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
    <tr class="hide">
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <select>
          <option value='pharmacist'>Pharmacist</option>
          <option value='doctor'>Doctor</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <select>
          <option value='A+'>A+</option>
          <option value='A'>A</option>
          <option value='B'>B</option>
          <option value='C'>C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data</button>
<p id="export"></p>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first return of your algoritm ($td.eq(i)) is

```
<td contenteditable="true"> 
    <select> 
        <option value="pharmacist">Pharmacist</option>
        <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

and `<td contenteditable="true">` is not have attribute value so that reson you have null value

and second value is

```
<td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
```

its same havn't attribut value so return null too

just use .text() its clear. because .text() will get only text in tag

i hope i  can help and understand what i say lol...

Comment: Question already answered. However, using text() works fine for the <td> tags that do NOT contain <select> inside them.